# Scan tree structure from bottom up?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

If given the following tree structure or one similar to it:

[image]

I would want the string ZYXWVUT returned. I know how to do this with a binary tree but not one that can have more than child nodes. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You would be essentially looking for a "reverse" breadth-first algorithm. Edit: Just read the tree, if you're looking for `ZYXWVUT` then that's simply a depth-first listing...

Comment: Looks like postorder traverse to me

Comment: To clarify: do you want to print the nodes by their depth in the tree? Because only by your example, it is complicated to say what is your question.

Answer (score 21):

This is called a [post-order traversal of a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order): you print the content of all subtrees of a tree before printing the content of the node itself.

[image: Post-order traversal]

This can be done recursively, like this (pseudocode):

```
function post_order(Tree node)
    foreach n in node.children
        post_order(n)
    print(node.text)
```

Comment: Edited to include a picture, hope you don't mind. As for the OP's concern "I know how to do this with a binary tree but not one that can have more than child nodes": I think tree traversals will work on a tree with any number of child nodes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are maintaining an ArrayList (say node_list) to track the number of nodes branching of from the current tree node, you can traverse the tree from the root till you find a node that has an empty node_list. This way you will be able to identify the leaf nodes of the tree. A recursive approach would work for this case. I haven't tested the code but I believe this should work for what you have asked:

If you are maintaining something similar to the class below to build your tree:

```
class Node {
     String data;
     ArrayList<Node> node_list;}
```

The following recursive function might be what you are looking for:

```
public void traverse_tree(Node n){
    if(n.node_list.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print(n.data);
    }
    else{
        for(Node current_node:n.node_list){
            traverse_tree(current_node);
        }
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }
}
```

Essentially what you are looking at is the Post-order Depth First traversal of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it

```
public void traverse(){
    for(Child child : this.children){
        child.traverse();
    }
    System.out.print(this.value);
}
```