# bottom up tree traversal starting from a particular leaf

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I am looking for a way to traverse a tree from bottom-up such that I could start at a particular leaf of my choosing, and then proceed to the root.

Expected Output: In my sample tree image in the link [sample tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaq0E.png), which was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062527/scan-tree-structure-from-bottom-up), the algorithm would return YXZWVUT if I specify starting from Y.

I'd be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the parent element at every node.

Comment: Depends on how you represent the tree. The main point is that you have to know each node's parent, this can be done by storing a parent pointer in each node, or using plain math formula like `x/2` in some implementation of binary trees, etc. You can easily achieve what you want if you know each node's parent && you know if a node is root

Comment: @shole I have a reference to the parent element at every node but I am stuck on how to do this efficiently via an algorithm. My tree is not a binary tree.

Comment: I dont get it. If you have a reference to parent, isn't it just loop till you get to the root? And it is the bound, as you access all node on the path exactly once only which is obviously inevitable. So what is you struggling about, maybe you can desribe more ao that we can help you :)

Comment: @shole Sorry if I didn't clarify properly. Starting from a leaf of my choosing -  in particular, the deepest node (leaf) -  I want to visit/print every node of the entire tree and ultimately end up at the root.

Comment: Got it, it seems more difficult to me now...In your sample tree, if V has one more child, which will be visited first? W or V's child?

Comment: Is the order that you print them important?

Comment: The only constraint with the order is to start from the selected leaf node, and proceed bottom-up, visiting all children before each parent, and ultimately ending up at the root. @shole If V has one more child, W is visited first (as all it's children have been visited), before V's child then V.

Comment: @Orphie Ok I got an idea, last question: So from your image, is both YXZW VU T and YXZW UV T acceptable?

Comment: @Orphie Also Is Y ZX WVUT acceptable? (Y visited before X; Z,X visited before W; But X is not immediately visited after Y)

Comment: @shole Yes both YXZW VU T and YXZW UV T are acceptable.

Comment: @shole   YZX WVUT is also acceptable, since it does not violate the constraint of visiting all the children before parent. Ideally, we'd want to examine the parent immediately we've examined all the children but non-immediacy is acceptable too.

Answer (score 4):

If i understood the question correctly, this would be the problem statement

**Traverse an n-ary tree, starting from a leaf node, up to the root, such that no node is traversed before all it's children are traversed. First node traversed will always be the leaf node, last node traversed will always be the root node.**

This can be solved by using two recursive functions, TraverseUp() is the main function which calls itself and one other recursive function PostOrderTraversal() which calls itself. Array A needs to be passed by reference and will contain the final traversed list. Here is some pseudo code:

```
TraverseUp(Array *A, Node *n) {
  // Add n to A to maintain bottom up nature
  if (!n) return;
  A.add(n)

  // Go to parent
  Node *p = n.parent();
  if (!p) return;

  // For each child of p other than n, do a post order traversal
  foreach(Node *c in p.children) {
    if (c == n) continue;
    PostOrderTraversal(A, c);
  }
  // When done with adding all p's children, continue traversing up
  TraverseUp(A, p);
}

// Standard implementation of post order traversal
PostOrderTraversal(Array *A, Node *n) {
  if (!n) return;
  foreach(Node *c in n.children) {
    PostOrderTraversal(A, c);
    A.add(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems nice! What is the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: It should be O(n)